# PHP checking if item exists in array and then return the value - convert to a function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Working on a WordPress site and using Advanced Custom Fields. I am looping through an flexible content array and creating an array from the return.

The issue is I need to return differently named images in an array but the images might be null (they can be empty).

This currently works:

```
"images" => [
    "image_one"   => ( $l['image_one']['url'] ? $l['image_one']['url'] : NULL ),
    /* etc */
]
```

But this is in a switch statement so I wanted to be able to pass the:

```
$l['image_one']['url']
```

To a function and only return the URL if there is one. However I could have a array where $l['image_three']['url'] is not set and not in the array returned so I will always get undefined offset notices.

I can carry on the way I am but its getting repetive and would rather be able to do e.g.:

```
 "image_one" => imageExists($l['image_one']['url'])
```

But of course I am already calling a key that doesn't exist (possibly). Is there an other methods of tidying up my shorthand if?

Comment: what is `$l` in your code ? do you loop some array and this is sub-array ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix Yeah sorry, $l is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) on your ternary condition:

```
function imageExists($image) {
    return isset($image['url']) ? $image['url'] : NULL;
}
```

And invoke with:

```
imageExists($l['image_one']);
```

If you're on a version >= PHP 7.0, you can use the null coalescing operator ([search here.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)) For:

```
function imageExists($image) {
    return $image['url'] ?? NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would just do it inline but since you are looking for a function:

```
function imageExists($arr = null) {
    return (empty($arr['url'])) ? null : $arr['url'];
}

imageExists($l['image_one']);
```